# a.exe will not take input after 2 lines

Tags: c++

I'm a bit new to c++, and wanted to do problems with it but I found that the input will not go over 2 lines. Can somebody help me with this? The input format is here http://www.usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=568. It is supposed to read in multiple lines of input to solve a problem.

For example, see the input below

Input Example:

```
3 3
40 75
50 35
10 45
40 76
20 30
40 40
```

when i paste this into console, expecting an answer from the code, the console cuts off after 75 on the second line. I want the entire thing to be inputted into the code, but instead only the first two lines are inputted.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int cow[100];
int limit[100];
int N, M;
int currMile = 0;

int main() {
    cin >> N >> M;
    for(int x = 0; x < N; x++) {
        int len, speed;
        cin >> len >> speed;
        for(int x = currMile; x < len + currMile; x++) {
            limit[x] = speed;
            currMile += 1;
        }
    }
    currMile = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
        int len, speed;
        cin >> len >> speed;
        for(int i = currMile; i < len + currMile; i++) {
            cow[i] = speed;
            currMile += 1;
        }
    }
    int max = 0;
    for(int h = 0; h < 100; h++) {
        if(cow[h] - limit[h] > max) {
            max = cow[h] - limit[h];
        }
    }
    cout << max;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't compile your program because you've used a non-standard header file.

Comment: Think on this for a moment: You have not told us what this code is supposed to do. You have told us that the code does not do it. Can we easily infer from an example that does not do what it s supposed to do what it should do?

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` should be replaced with `#include <iostream>` to make the code compatible with standard c++

Comment: Since you increment both `x` and `currMile`, `x < len + currMile` is either never true or never false. If it's never false, `limit[x] = speed;` will write outside your array, which has undefined behaviour.

Comment: A note about Stack Overflow's goal: To create a repository of high-quality questions and answers for programmers. The question is what gets the process started and hopefully gets the asker an answer they can use, but the asker is only the first, and the question must withstand the test of time to help future askers or it is not useful. Links are unreliable. The hosting site may go down, shuffle its links, or change the content  at the link. Firewalls may block access. Users may be afraid to click the link because of what may be waiting on the other side. Do not use links.

Comment: My guess is UB because of an out of bounds index being used. Do you use `g++` or `clang++`? If so, add `-ggdb -fsanitize=address` when compiling and it'll show you where it is (`limit[x] = speed;` when `x == 100`)

Comment: @molbdnilo THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're asking. You want your program to loop over?

```
while (cin >> N >> M)
{
  // rest of your code
}
```

Comment: No, when I try to put an input (ex. the input below), it cuts off after 75.
(every 2 numbers, there is a new line)
3 3 
40 75
50 35
10 45
40 76
20 30

Comment: @TedLyngmo Sorry for the confusion, I edited it.